# recv() char array size

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I'm working on implementing a C++ client server chat program to learn more / practice socket programming. I'm using winsockV2.

Briefly,
the client program connects to a server, who stores the client socket in a vector
client program sends messages for the server to distribute to other clients in the vector.

The problem I think I'm running into is that the clients and server are receiving the message and storing it in a `char message[256]` and if the message is shorter than 256, strange chars are displayed when I `std::cout << message;` which I'm being told is uninitialized memory. Here's an example of the output:

```
k:message from client to other client╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠(■o
```

Is there some way of creating a character array of the size of the received message? i.e

```
char recvMessage[4096];
int s = recv(socket, recvMessage, sizeof(recvMessage),0);
char recvOutput[strlen(recvMessage)] = recvMessage;
std::cout << recvOutput << std::endl;
```

Otherwise what is your solution for `recv`'ing messages which you do not know the length of?

If I'm being a complete idiot, please be kind, I came from PHP. classes are below:

## SVR.CPP

See `receiveMessages()` and `distributeMessages()` functions

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "svr.h"

svr::svr()
{
    //WSA Business I don't understand
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err;

    /* Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h */
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (err != 0)
    {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* Winsock DLL.                                  */
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", err);
    }
    //End of WSA Business

    //get addressSize
    addressSize = sizeof(address);
    //set address data members
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(444);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    //init sListen
    sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(sListen, (sockaddr*)&address, addressSize);
}

svr::~svr()
{
}

void svr::start()
{
    std::thread newConnThread(&svr::newConnection, this);
    newConnThread.join();
}

void svr::receiveMessages(int clientIndex)
{
    std::cout << "\tsvr::recv thread started for client index:" << clientIndex << std::endl;

    //create char arr
    char recvMessage[256];

    //forever
    while (true)
    {
        //receive message and input it to recvMessage char arr.
        recv(clients[clientIndex], recvMessage, sizeof(recvMessage), 0);

        //if message is not null, send out to other clients
        if (recvMessage != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "\t\tINFO:Received message of length: " << std::strlen(recvMessage) << " size: " << sizeof(recvMessage) << " : " << recvMessage << std::endl;
            distributeMessages(recvMessage, clientIndex);
        }
    }
}

//distributes messages to all clients in vector. called by receiveMessages function, normally in rMessages thread.
void svr::distributeMessages(std::string message, int clientIndex)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++)
    {
        if (clientIndex != i)
        {
            send(clients[i], message.c_str(), message.length(), 0);
        }
        else
        {
            //would have sent to self, not useful.
        }
    }
}

//accepts new connections and adds sockets to vector.
void svr::newConnection()
{
    //mark for accept, unsure of somaxconn value;
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);

    std::cout << "\tSERVER: awaiting new connections..." << std::endl;
    while (true)
    {
        //accept connection and push on to vector.
        clients.push_back(accept(sListen, (sockaddr*)&address, &addressSize));

        //responds to new clients.
        const char *message = "Hi, you've successfully connected!";

        int clientIndex = clients.size() - 1;
        int sent = send(clients[clientIndex], message, 33, 0);

        //start new receiveMessage thread
        std::thread newClient(&svr::receiveMessages, this, clientIndex);

        //detach here, let newConn thread operate without depending on receiveMessages
        newClient.detach();
    }
    std::cout << "\tSERVER: no longer listening for new connections" << std::endl;
 }
```

## CLI.CPP

See `cSend()` and `cRecv()` functions

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cli.h"

cli::cli(char *ip)
{
    //WSA
    {
        WORD wVersionRequested;
        WSADATA wsaData;
        int err;

        // Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte,highbyte) macro declared in windef.h
        wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

        err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

        if (err != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "WSAStartup failed with the error: " << err;
        }
    }

    //get addressSize 
    addressSize = sizeof(address);

    //set address struct data members
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(444);

    //if ip empty, prompt user;
    if (ip == NULL)
    {
        std::string ipInput;
        std::cout << "\n\tConnect to which IP: ";
        std::cin >> ipInput;
        address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipInput.c_str());
    }
    else
    {
        address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    std::cout << "\n\tYour username: ";
    std::cin >> uname;
}

cli::~cli()
{
}

void cli::start()
{
    try
    {
        //hold string
        char message[33];

        std::cout << "\n\tcli::start() called";
        int conRet;

        //connects to server socket & receives a message, stores in it message variable
        conRet = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&address, (int)addressSize);
        recv(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0);

        std::cout << "\n\tSERVER: " << message;

        //starts threads, pass this for object scope.
        std::thread sendThread(&cli::cSend, this);
        std::thread recvThread(&cli::cRecv, this);

        //this function (start) will return/end when send and recv threads end.
        sendThread.join();
        recvThread.join();
    }
    catch (std::exception e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void cli::cSend()
{
    std::cout << "\n\tcli::send thread started";
    //char arr for sending str;
    std::string getLine;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\t" << uname << ":" << std::flush;
        //set to "" because i suspected the value remains in the string after a loop.
        std::string message = "";

        //get input, put it in message
        std::getline(std::cin, message);

        //get full message
        std::string fullMessage = uname + ":" + message;

        //get constant int, size of fullMessage
        const int charArrSize = fullMessage.length();

        std::cout << "\t\tINFO: Sending character array of length: " << charArrSize << " size: " << sizeof(fullMessage.c_str()) << " : " << fullMessage.c_str() << std::endl;

        //sends it
        send(sock, fullMessage.c_str(), charArrSize, 0);
    }
}

void cli::cRecv()
{
    std::cout << "\n\tcli::recv  thread started";

    //initialize arr to 0, will hopefully help avoid the weird chars in the cout
    char recvMessage[256]{ '\0' };

    while (true)
    {
        recv(sock, recvMessage, sizeof(recvMessage), 0);

        std::cout << "\t\tINFO:Received message of length: " << std::strlen(recvMessage) << " size: " << sizeof(recvMessage) << " : " << recvMessage << std::endl;

        std::cout << recvMessage << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is your solution for recv'ing messages which you do not know the
>   length of?

`recv()` tells you the length of the message it received. You don't have to wonder what it is. That's `recv()`'s return value.

```
 int s = recv(socket, recvMessage, sizeof(recvMessage),0);
```

See -- there you go. It's right here in front of you. It's `s`. Of course if there was an error `s` would be negative and you need to check for that. But, ignoring that little detail, your worries are over: `s` is the length of your message you just received.

```
 char recvOutput[strlen(recvMessage)] = recvMessage;
```

That's not going to work. What is `strlen()` doing here? `strlen()` computes the size of the string, expecting the string to be an old-fashioned, C-style character string that's terminated by a `\0` byte. `recv()` does not terminate anything it receives with a `\0` byte. Instead, it returns the actual character count.

And, besides, this won't work anyway. You can't initialize an array this way.

Your obvious intent here, apparently, is to expect to receive a text string as message. Well, since your language of choice is `C++`, and you tagged your question as such, the logical conclusion is that you should be using what `C++` gives you to deal with text strings: the `std::string` class:

```
std::string recvOutput{recvMessage, recvMessage+s};
```

There you go. Mission accomplished. Since you already known the length of the received message in `s`, as we've determined before (and after double-checking that `s` is not negative), you can simply use `std::string`'s existing constructor that initializes the new string given an iterator, or a pointer, to the start and the end of string.

When dealing with low-level operating system interfaces, like sockets, you have no choice but to use primitive data types, like plain `char` arrays and buffers, because that's the only thing that the operating system understands. But, with the rich set of templates and classes offered by the C++ library, your code should switch to using C++ classes and templates at the first opportunity, in order to be able to use all those resources. As such, as soon as you've determined how big is the text string `recv()` just came up with, just stuff it into a `std::string` before figuring out what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough info. I didn't think to use the return value!

With the std::string constructor, I know the second parameter is the size, but why do you use `recvMessage+s` ?